# Render database image from MVC Controller Action

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, email, outlook

I have a mailing campaign that generates HTML emails that get sent out to customers periodically.

Recently I changed the system to allow configuration of certain image elements within the mail-shot to be configured by the end user rather than static. These images are stored in the database with a GUID Id and loaded via a Controller Action as shown below:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "id")]
public virtual ActionResult Image(Guid id)
{
   FileItem picture = FileService.GetItem(id);
   return picture != null ? File(picture.FileData, picture.ContentType) : null;
}
```

In case the email does not render correctly within the email client there is a link to view the same mail-shot in the browser.

In the browser all the images load and display correctly, however my problem is within the email client (in this case Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2010) where the  images referenced by the above method do not load ONLY the static images are displayed.

As an example an image element that loads fine would be a static file like:

```
<img src="http://www.foo.com/es/spacer6.gif" width="1" height="8" border="0" alt="" />
```

An element that won't load fine is like this:

```
<img src="http://www.foo.com/Packages/Image/0c6d126d-8f62-4e28-9963-7377e73c0482" style="border-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1;border-right-width:1;border-top-width:1;border-left-width:1;border-color:#333;" alt="..." />
```

So both coming from the same domain just one is static and one is loaded via the controller action above. I am guessing that the Outlook client doesn't like the fact that this is a link to an external "resource", as it wouldn't know it was an image based on the URL alone.

Is there anyway to change my controller action to "trick" Outlook into thinking this is simply a static image URL or is there just a better way to do this.

Comment: There is no difference for a user agent whether something is served from a static file or generated from code. The user agent does not know how your back-end is implemented. Put an HTTP debugging proxy like Fiddler in between and check the differences. _Maybe_ Outlook is being picky because the latter URI has no image type exension, you could try adding ".png" (or the correct extension for the according image type).

Comment: @CodeCaster Agreed, I had considered changing the controller method to be a string that included the image type extension. My other thought is to modernise the file storage (as I have in other areas of the system) by storing the images in Azure File Storage rather than in the database, that way I can serve them up with the URL direct to the storage location.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I changed the mechanism for storing the images to Azure file storage and now with links to real files it all works.

Answer (score 0):

I use next code prom puresourcecod.com :

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

...

public ActionResult Hello(string text)
{
    //Create new image
    Image img = new Bitmap(100, 50);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //Do some drawing
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 24);
    PointF drawingPoint = new PointF(10, 10);

    g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, drawingPoint);

    //Return Image
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

    ms.Position = 0;

    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `picture.ContentType` contains what it should contain (e.g. "image/png" if the image is a PNG).

Otherwise perhaps Outlook depends on having the 'right' extensions. To find out you could add proper extensions to your guid-URLs and then use this:

```
public virtual ActionResult Image(string id)
{
    string s = id.Substring(0, id.IndexOf(".")); // a "." is now required
    Guid guid = Guid.Parse(s);
    FileItem picture = FileService.GetItem(guid);
    return picture != null ? File(picture.FileData, picture.ContentType) : null;
}
```